# AM-Receiver circuit, problems with saturation?

Tags: antenna, amplitude-modulation

I have a question about this specific circuit. I marked the potential-point I have "problems" with. I think there will be saturation in this point at some time. This point doesn't look to be able to discharge, because the diode is blocking, so how will you pass a signal after a while. I have a strong feeling that I miss something, maybe there is somebody who can help me out.

[OA91 datasheet here](http://rfelektronik.se/manuals/Datasheets/OA91.pdf)

[image]

https://www.circuits-diy.com/simple-am-receiver-circuit/

Comment: The VERY simple circuit has DC current running through the headphones maybe damaging them and causing distortion.

Comment: In the [OA91 datasheet](http://rfelektronik.se/manuals/Datasheets/OA91.pdf) see the botto haf of page 2 for reverse current Typially 17 uA at 1.5 so may be in the 0.1 uA range here (maybe :-)). || Germanium devices tend to be high leakage compared to silicon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I think there will be saturation in this point at some time. This
> point doesn't look to be able to discharge, because the diode is
> blocking, so how will you pass a signal after a while.*

I believe that the OA91 germanium diode will have significant leakage and therefore alleviate the problem you mentioned but, if you were thinking about building one of these then, I'd be considering adding a 10 kΩ resistor across the 100 nF capacitor with the red dot attached.

Comment: Doesnt matter, thanks for your answer! Yes maybe although I couldnt find evidence in the datasheet that the diode has a high leakage. I think first I try it without adaptations only to see whats happening maybe it works but I hope not ;D

Comment: @javagreenhorn yes try it without the resistor first. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: I cannot vote yet ;D. But I can accept I think, sorry I am new to this :)

Comment: I understand @javagreenhorn